# Can't find FileName in Http headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to read an uploaded file from a multi-part form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:17034/api/v1/reports/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="myFile" id="myFile" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="Description" id="Description" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="Content" id="content" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My controller action looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("reports/create")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Create()
{
   var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
   await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

   foreach (HttpContent ctnt in provider.Contents)
   {
      //I want to ensure I read text files as a stream so want
      //to check the file extension
      var fileName = ctnt.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName //NULL FOR FILE INPUT
   }
```

If I check the content disposition for the file input when I submit my form, I get this:

```
{form-data; name="myFile"}
CreationDate: null
DispositionType: "form-data"
FileName: null
FileNameStar: null
ModificationDate: null
Name: "\"myFile\""
Parameters: Count = 1
ReadDate: null
Size: null
dispositionType: "form-data"
parameters: Count = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> {form-data; name="myFile"}
>   Name: "\"myFile\""

This is because you're checking the form data with the name `myFile`. You should be checking the one with the name `Content`:

[image]